# ShareThis not working on custom divs

Tags: javascript, sharethis

http://test.cota.org/campaigns/COTAforTimothyA/blog/Images-How-will-they-appear-just-to-rename

I am using ShareThis two ways. The right hand side is using their built in buttons. I write some custom og at the top of the page so that it references this whole site as a whole and not just this individual blog. 
In the content of the post i have a Share This Post on Facebook.

```
<div data-network="facebook" data-url="http://test.cota.org/campaigns/COTAforTimothyA/blog/Images-How-will-they-appear-just-to-rename">Share This Post on Facebook</div>
```

I am calling JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=MYID&product=custom-share-buttons"></script>
```

From all I read the data-network="facebook" should trigger the share on the data-url. It is acting like nothing is happening at all. What am I missing in sharing custom buttons?

Comment: Have you added the sharethis js on top of the page

Answer (score 11):

I figured out that the custom divs also need a class — st-custom-button — to make them work.

It doesn't actually say that anywhere, which is why I didn't do it, but I finally noticed it's in one of the examples on [this](http://www.sharethis.com/support/customization/how-to-set-custom-buttons/) page, so I thought I'd give it a try. And it works. >.<